# I don't know what is wrong with my condition statements

Tags: python, conditional-statements

**Its not working  this is what I am trying to do.**

**finding out the tax of a person and subtract some based on their status and dependents my expected output is the user will enter its income then will multiply how much tax will be deducted and will also deduct some based on their status and how many dependents**

***They have:***

```
Income: 500000
Status: Married
Dependents= 3   
Tax = 25000
```

```
income = float(input("your income: "))
if income <= 100000:
    initialIncome = income * .5 
elif income in range (100001,250000):
    initialIncome = income * .10
elif income in range (250001,500000):
    initialIncome = income * .15
elif income >= 500001:
    initialIncome = income * .20

status = input("status (s,m,w,d) ")
if status == "S":
    S = 10000
elif status == "M":
    S = 20000
elif status == "W":
    S = 10000
elif status == "D":
    S = 30000

dependents = float(input("dependents num: "))
if dependents >= 5:
    dependentsPrice = 50000
if dependents <= 5:
    dependentsPrice = 10000 * dependents


totalTax = initialIncome - (status + dependents)

print(totalTax)
```

Comment: What is the current answer you are getting and what is the desired output?

Comment: Income: 500000
Status: Married
Dependents: 3
Tax = 25000

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: your income: 500000
status (s,m,w,d) m
dependents num: 3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_7696/1455429402.py in <module>
     26 
     27 
---> 28 totalTax = initialIncome - (status + dependents)
     29 
     30 

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str

Comment: this is what i got. i should multiply the income to the specific percentage then I need to subtract the tax based on status and the number of dependents.

Comment: You forgot to use S and not status: 
totalTax = initialIncome - (S + dependents)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code:

- You are using status in `totalTax` instead of `S`.
- You must add `.upper()` to convert all the input strings to upper case as you have used uppercase in *`if statements`*.

```
income = float(input("your income: "))
if income <= 100000:
    initialIncome = income * .5 
elif income in range (100001,250000):
    initialIncome = income * .10
elif income in range (250001,500001):
    initialIncome = income * .15
elif income >= 500001:
    initialIncome = income * .20
else:
    print("Invalid input")
    initaialIncome = 0


# Here you must add upper to convert all the strings to upper case
status = input("status (s,m,w,d) ").upper()
#To prevent undefined error
S = 
if status == "S":
    S = 10000
elif status == "M":
    S = 20000
elif status == "W":
    S = 10000
elif status == "D":
    S = 30000
#In case user enters wrong input.
else:
    print("Invalid input")


dependents = float(input("dependents num: "))
if dependents >= 5:
    dependentsPrice = 50000 *dependents
if dependents <= 5:
    dependentsPrice = 10000 * dependents

# Here status is string. I suppose you are trying to use S.
#here use dependsPrice
totalTax = initialIncome - (S + dependentsPrice) 

print(totalTax)
```

Comment: NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_7696/993018332.py in <module>
     26 
     27 
---> 28 totalTax = initialIncome - (S + dependents)
     29 
     30 print(totalTax)

NameError: name 'S' is not defined
i don't understand

Comment: can I ask how would I correct this formula: I want it to be  500,000 * 15%  = 75 000, then subtract 75 000 to 20 000 because it is married  ,then it will be 55 000 (the dependents is 3 ) so it will be 10000 * 3 equals to 30000. 55 000 * 30 000 will be 25 000. but what I did gives a different answer

Comment: this code will not work properly. python range generator is not designed to test, whether float is between some numbers. You should use 10000 <= income < 20000 or similar conditional statement. For floats income in range(10000, 200000) will always return false (try by yourself i.e. 0.5 in range(0,1) ), and moreover will consume considerable amount of time. Also, your if...elif...elif does not have else clause, so S may be not defined, if none of SMWD was selected by user.